# function str_slug is deprecated and not working, what should i do?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I was trying to use Str_slug but it is not working in laravel 5.8.
I am using PhpStorm latest version.

$product->slug = Str_slug('$request->title');

[Check the image for more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH0Bj.png)

```
public function ProductStore(StoreValidation $request){
    $product = new product();
    $product->category_id = 1;
    $product->brand_id = 1;
    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->desc = $request->desc;
    $product->slug = Str_slug('$request->title');
    $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    $product->offer_price = $request->offer;
    $product->status = 1;
    $product->admin_id = 1;
    // Saving Product information into product table
    $product->save();

    if ($request->hasFile('uploadFile')){
        $image = $request->file('uploadFile');
        $img = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('image/product/' .$img);

        $img_ins = Image::make($image)->resize(220,294);
        $img_ins->save($location);

        $product_img = new product_image();
        $product_img->product_id = $product->id;
        $product_img->image_name = $img;

        $product_img->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin_panel.pages.admin-addProduct');
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is the *best* solution but you could always just add it back to your project. https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-helpers/blob/master/src/helpers.php#L791

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Str::slug()` (Illuminate\Support\Str) instead of deprecated `str_slug()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-slug

Comment: Thank you it worked i checked your comment ... i used Str::slug() as u suggested.